# How is Android root filesystem created for Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, filesystems, qemu, device

I am working on the Android ICS AOSP for Android emulator.

When I compile and create an Android image and load it using the Android SDK (emulator), I can see the set of devices under `/dev/`; but when I look at the `<AOSP>/out/target/product/generic/root/dev/` folder it's empty.

How does this `/dev/` folder get these devices during boot up time? Is there a configuration file in the `<AOSP>/system/` folder which helps it to populate the list of devices?

Also, what if I want to update or add more devices, e.g. `/dev/block/sda1`, so that I can mount another QEMU raw image as `sda1` or similar?
I can see the emulator under `-qemu` as `-hda/-hdb file  use 'file' as IDE hard disk 0/1 image`, which I can use.

Are all the QEMU options working in the Android emulator?